# SFML Can't Start Application

Tags: c++, windows, shared-libraries, libraries, sfml

I am running a project which use **SFML** and who works **perfectly fine on Linux**.
I am now Compiling my project on **Window** and it works.

I am Using **Cmake** actually.
The thing is when I start my **SFML APPLICATION** it just **doesn't run**.
I mean when I start it, The main's first line of code isn't executed.

The error seems to be **due to Shared Libraries Linking** but I can't figure Why ?

I've Included the **SFML dlls in the binary directory**, so I didn't got (explicitly at least) errors about **shared libraries**. **(When running Through a terminal)**

**I do not Compile my program with static SFML Linking otherwise I wouldn't have this question**

I've also **compiled SFML myself** (and installed it ofc) and use the same Compiler ("**-G"MinGW Makefiles"**) to build my SFML Application.

I've seen someone who got a driver's update problem, but I've already tried the solution

The error code is:

when running through a Git-bash terminal. (No explicit Error)

```
echo $?  -> 127
(so -1 at runtime)
```

And when Running through CLion:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741792 (0xC0000020)
```

If someone can help me it would be great!

EDIT:

When using dependency walker (and select SFML dlls)
I got an error too **This files is not a valid 32-bit or 64-bit Windows Module**
But I do not understand why since I've compile SFML myself

Comment: Use dependency walker to debug any missing dependency

Comment: It probably requires runtime libraries from mingw.